# li alignment behaves strange if remove new lines after items

Tags: html, css, alignment

I have next navigation block in html template

```
<nav class="navigation">
    <ul class="nav">
        <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 5</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 6</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

with css

```
.navigation {
     padding: 0 0 19px;
 }

.nav {
    font: 20px/22px "futura_demi_c", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-align: justify;
    text-align-last: justify;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.nav:after {
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.nav li {
    display: inline-block;
}
.nav a {
    color: #020202;
}
```

Items have to be aligned justify in navigation block and occupy all entire width. And they are, if I use the code above.

But if i remove new lines after each 'li' all items move to the right without spaces between them

```
<nav class="navigation">
    <ul class="nav">
        <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li><li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li><li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li><li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li><li><a href="#">Item 5</a></li><li><a href="#">Item 6</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Is it normal behaviour or my css is wrong?
Behaviour is the same for all browsers.
Jsfiddle examples: correct - http://jsfiddle.net/x9zfP/1 wrong - http://jsfiddle.net/AMK8z/1/
Tnx!

Comment: There must be some additional condition, I see no difference between the two [JSFiddle 1](http://jsfiddle.net/x9zfP/), [JSFiddle 2](http://jsfiddle.net/AMK8z/).

Comment: Example was wrong, i put id="nav" instead of class="nav"

Comment: There are correct examples http://jsfiddle.net/x9zfP/1/ and http://jsfiddle.net/AMK8z/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behaviour is expected, because of the [`display: inline-block`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#display-prop). This means whitespace between the elements will be considered.

See also [CSS-Tricks - Fighting the Space Between Inline Block Elements](http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/)

Answer (score 0):

your css is wrong, "." is for class and "#" for id.
your ul has an id, so first replace all occurencies of ".nav" with "#nav"

here the correct css:

```
.navigation {
     padding: 0 0 19px;
}
#nav {
    font: 20px/22px "futura_demi_c", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-align: justify;
    text-align-last: justify;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width:100%;
    display:table
}
/* useless
#nav:after {
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
*/
#nav li {
    display: table-cell;
}
#nav a {
    color: #020202;
}
```

basically your parent element need to have a width, and child need the property "display:table-cell".

Comment: Yes, it's just an mistake in example. Of course there should be class="nav"

Comment: Yes, cool, looks like your example works well. But there are examples of what i said: jsfiddle.net/x9zfP/1 and jsfiddle.net/AMK8z/1

Comment: my example is the correct version of your code, see Olaf link for full explanation

Comment: You example is good, but it don't solve the problem. If I'm not mistaken, in your example we can't alight first element tight to the left side and last element to the right side. Last element will always have some space after it.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior is normal because your `li` has no padding or margin, so there's nothing there to keep the split apart.

This fixes your issue:

```
.nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 30px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AMK8z/1/